# Html5 web pages in a window

Tags: ajax, html, jquery, window

I'm trying to get a web page in a window within a web page, so basily what I want is something like a standed os, 
you have a exe it opens with in a window, well I want that but in HTML5

Would I use Ajax?

Anything would be helpful at this stage!

Thanks jrop

Comment: You mean an `<iframe>`? Why the HTML 5 requirement? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem you don't need HTML5. You can solve it by using jQuery.

jQuert window plugin (You can choose one of them depending on your need):

- http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/
- http://hernan.amiune.com/labs/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin.html

  - http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html
  - http://pierrebertet.net/projects/jquery_superbox/

Comment: Thank you all! I feel like a numtie now it's so clear how to do it haha

Answer (score 0):

If you want an actual window then you would use [`open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open). If you want a pseudo-window inside a page, then you would use [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element). If you don't want an actual page, but just a chunk of HTML then you would use [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills) to create the elements in the page (and possibly Ajax techniques to get the data over HTTP if you don't have it in the page already).